# (Illustrator) Why do the colors change when I "Save for Web" by using an action?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, rgb, color-profile

If I Save for Web in Illustrator, there is a very slight color change, which is to be expected. However, when I create a "Save for Web" action and apply it instead of directly using Save for Web, the color is much more vibrant.

I used the exact same settings as when I recorded the action- the only difference is that I'm using an action shortcut so that I don't have to jam my fingers with alt-cmd-shift-s every time. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: If you are saving in PNG format, you can use "pngcheck -v file.png" to look at the contents.  In particular, see if there are differences in the color management chunks (iCCP, cHRM, and/or gAMA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you working in CMYK mode?

if so, that is the issue. when the computer is trying to display the CMYK colors in RGB things get out of whack. If you are working on something to be displayed by screens just start you file on RGB.

Comment: I was in RGB. I actually solved the issue by restarting Illustrator. Apparently if you change the color profile settings and try to use actions to save, it will use the old settings until you restart. At least that is what I think is going on.

Comment: @Justin you should write this up as an answer and mark it correct, so it'll be easy for others to find, when looking for the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the Preset area, next to the preset name, there is a dropdown menu. Uncheck "Convert to sRGB." That should do it.

Comment: Please add a screenshot showing what you mean ...  Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

For my document I get different colors to what I see in Illustrator when I export with option *Anti-aliasing* set to **Art Optimized** (Image Size tab in dialog right panel). When this option is set to **Type Optimized** colors are fine. As it is possible to specify in "Save for Web" action what anti-aliasing to use it may happen that you specified different values there and in the export dialog.

Comment: Hi Zooloo, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

When you Save for Web in Illustrator, the colors can be change. In the Optimize menu (upper right corner of the save window for the web, next to the preset name field) if the option convert to sRGB is actived, that can affect and change the Hexadecimal colors (#8cc63e, #470C0C).